# update progress between pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a website that uses the ajax UpdateProgress and UpdatePanel controls.  I know that I can't use this same method to show a process indicator between pages.  But, the user's would like to see that some work is being done while they are going to a new link.  What are some ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The built-in browser progress indicators are not enough?

Answer (score 0):

what i've done recently is to use jQuery to show an animated gif (e.g. rotating circle) (for the links i know are gonna take awhile to load).